# Apple switching to SMB, but SMB doesn't handle permissions the POSIX way: so what are they doing?

Tags: smb, afp, acl

Rumor has it that Apple is switching from AFP to SMB for their file sharing.

However, SMB has always had a problem with permissions (i.e. everything is executable or everything is not executable).

**How have they gotten around this?**

And **how can I do the same with a Linux SMB server?**

Comment: Have you seen https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions?

Comment: I hadn't. Does this need to be enabled manually? When my OS X machine connects to the Linux machine and I call `touch a` (where `a` did not previously exist), it is given execute permissions. This is the expected behavior when the two don't know they're talking POSIX... So what do I have to do to make them do so?

Comment: your question seems speculative as Apple hasn't actually moved yet. Given their extensive experience creating a plug-and-play desktop experience on top of what is really not much more than System V, I would wait until the actual move is made to worry. Until then I'm not sure anyone outside of Apple's development team could offer you any reliable advice. My link was simply meant to illustrate that smb and POSIX can coexist